# Can I add more jquery selectors to cheerio? (node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I've been playing around with cheerio and I noticed it doesn't seem to support certain selectors specified in the jquery reference, specifically ":odd" and ":even".  Is there a way to use these by importing the jquery package into my program?  Or is that something that has to be implemented into the cheerio code?

Here's my code:

```
//var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var jquery = require('./jquery-1.10.2');

var fs = require('fs');

    $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('c:/java/bushkill_mls.html'));

    var odds = [];
    var evens = [];

    $('tr:odd').each(function() {
        odds = odds.concat($(this).text());

        });
        console.log(odds);
```

You can see I tried importing jquery but I couldn't get past importing it without getting the error "window is not defined" so obviously this seems like a node compatibility problem.  So is there any way to increase the selector library in cheerio or maybe import another module that has the jquery selector functions I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something simple to cheerio like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

cheerio.prototype.odd = function() {
    var odds = [];
    this.each(function(index, item) {
        if (index % 2 == 1) {
            odds.push(item);
        }
    });

    return cheerio(odds);
}

var $ = cheerio.load("<div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>");
$("div").odd().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Yes, it doesn't match jquery exactly, but it's similar to how cheerio deals with jquery's `:eq(n)` selector.

Comment: hmm, so if I get this right, I can index all of the <td>'s sequentially on my own and then pick all the odd and even ones from this new index.  That's a great idea but how would I index all the <td>'s sequentially?? (I'm still pretty new to javascript)

Comment: I just realized I could add all the td elements to an array and count them that way - duh!  Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the other part of your question :

> import another module that has the jquery selector functions I need?

Whatever you can't do with cheerio, you can do with [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). It implements the full DOM and enables you to inject jQuery and other libraries.

As a downside, it slows down your code and takes a lot more memory, so it's better used only when no other alternative, eg: when you have more to do than simple html parsing.