# Scraping w/ Node.js + Cheerio - Duplicates, selector within selector creates duplicate return

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Here is the situation. I am using Node.js and cheerio 
My console log return is fine except for some duplicate stuff cause by the site structure...

My script:

```
var request = require ('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    chart = [];                              

request('http://www.website-X.com', function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $('tr', '#chart_body').each(function(){
                    var rank = $(this).text().trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ';');
                    chart.push(rank);
        });
        console.log(chart);                             
    }
});
```

---

The site structure (simplified):

```
                    <table id="chart_body">
                        <tr><!-- 1 Info I need --></td>
                        <tr><!-- 2 Info I need --></td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr> Duplicate info as 1  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        <tr><!-- 3 Info I need --></td>
                        <tr><!-- 4 Info I need --></td>
                        <tr><!-- 5 Info I need --></td>
                        <tr><!-- 6 Info I need --></td>
                    </table>
```

---

My console log return:

```
'1;Wolfenstein;330,703;330,703;1',
  'Wolfenstein',
'2;Wolfenstein;188,200;188,200;1',
  'Wolfenstein',
'3;Minecraft;126,041;215,109;2',
  'Minecraft','
```

---

My console log return is fine except for the duplicate stuff . It's cause in the site structure the selector tr has another tr within it. I can't get rid of 'tr tr'.
The tr's also don't have unique classes to further select.

Please help. 
Thanks!!!
-Aldo

Oh and lastly... The pesky single quote at the beginning and end of every return. I can't take it out.

Comment: You might try taking a look at these answers out there, which are trying to do a similar thing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Answer (score 0):

If the `tr` rows are consistently duplicated, you could only select the odd ones:

```
$('tr', '#chart_body').odd()
```

Using the function from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673196/3047500)

Answer (score 0):

How about the child selector? `#chart_body > tr` should do the job.